# How can we get the size of an array that is passed into the function?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

**This is my program, can someone tell me how to get the right value of 'n'(which is size of array) here without passing it to function?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char * findFrequency (int input1[],int input2)
{
    int n = sizeof(input1) / sizeof(input1[0]);
    
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(input1[i] == input2) 
         count++;
    }
    string ch;
    if(count == 0) 
     ch = to_string(input2) + " not present"; 
    else 
     ch = to_string(input2) + " comes " + to_string(count) + " times";
    std::cout << ch << "\nn = " << n;
}
int main ()
{
    int a[] = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    findFrequency(a, 1);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `sizeof(input1) / sizeof(input1[0])` work?

Comment: You can't. This is one of many reasons why you should use a std::vector instead of an array.

Comment: @vahancho That only works with proper arrays. It won't work with a pointer to the first element of an array, which is how array type function arguments are implemented.

Comment: @vahancho No, it's giving value 2.

Comment: @KAditi -- Please note that this: `char * findFrequency (int input1[],int input2)` is exactly the same as `char * findFrequency (int* input1,int input2)`,  That is the reason why it is 2.  `sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Okay, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can always use a template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void findFrequency (T(&input1)[N], int input2)
{
    // input1 is the array
    // N is the size of it

    //int n = sizeof(input1) / sizeof(input1[0]);

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(input1[i] == input2)
         count++;
    }
    string ch;
    if(count == 0)
     ch = to_string(input2) + " not present";
    else
     ch = to_string(input2) + " comes " + to_string(count) + " times";
    std::cout << ch << "\nn = " << N;
}
int main ()
{
    int a[] = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    findFrequency(a, 1);
}
```